# Can't access recovery mode by holding shift

Tags: recovery-mode

I have Xubuntu 14.04 and I cannot access recovery mode via holding down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key. I read almost everywhere that this is how you do it.

Does that work for Xubuntu as well or just Ubuntu?

The reason this is needed is because I somehow lost `sudo` on my user account and cant access any root commands.

Comment: Try pressing `Shift` rapidly while booting until it says `GRUB Loading, please wait...`, then immediately hold down `Shift`.

Comment: That does not work for me. thanks. Just boots into desktop. I have an SSD and booting takes like 7 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to access the recovery mode menu ONLY and finally after trying <kbd>ESC</kbd>.  At no time and in no way did the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key work for me.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me hours!